# How does one display, Setters and getters in C# and declare them to the Main method

Tags: c#

How does one declare this code in the main method. My preference are mainly for calculations and constructions to happen in the class and only declare the class in the main.

```
namespace Namsolution_Payroll_System
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            ITDepartment emp = new ITDepartment();
            emp.DisplayITEmployee();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class Employee
    {
        //please review other data types you can use before submitting: Self note!!
        public string _first_Name;
        public string _last_Name;
        public DateTime  _date_Of_Birth;
        public string _gender;                               // (male or female columes) : Self Note
        public double _staff_Number;                            //this should be unique
        public string _department;
        public DateTime _date_Of_Employment;
        public string _position;                                     //rank

        //Code set to Variables
        public void SetFirstName(string employeeName)
        {
            _first_Name = employeeName;
        }
        public void SetLastName(string employeeLastName)
        {
            _last_Name = employeeLastName;
        }
        public void SetdateOfBirth(DateTime employeeDateOfBith)
        {
            _date_Of_Birth = employeeDateOfBith;
        }
        public void SetGender(string employeeGender)
        {
            _gender = employeeGender;
        }
        public void SetStaffNumber(double employeeStaffNumber)
        {
            _staff_Number = employeeStaffNumber;
        }
        public void SetDepartment(string employeeDepartment)
        {
            _department = employeeDepartment;
        }
        public void SetDateOfEmployment(DateTime employeedateOfEmployment)
        {
            _date_Of_Employment = employeedateOfEmployment;
        }
        public void SetPosition(string employeePositon)
        {
            _position = employeePositon;
        }

        //Input Code
        public string GetFirstName()
        {
            return _first_Name;
        }
        public string GetLastTName()
        {
            return _last_Name;
        }
        public DateTime GetDateOfBirth()
        {
            return _date_Of_Birth;
        }
        public string GetGender()
        {
            return _gender;
        }
        public double GetStaffNumber()
        {
            return _staff_Number;
        }
        public string GetDepartment()
        {
            return _department;
        }
        public DateTime GetDateOfEmployment()
        {
            return _date_Of_Employment;
        }
        public string GetPosition()
        {
            return _position;
        }

        public void DisplayEmployee()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is from Employee class");
        }

    }





    class ITDepartment : Employee
    {
        public void DisplayITEmployee()
        {
            DisplayEmployee();
            Console.WriteLine("This is from ITDepartment class");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: BTW. Why not use Getters and Setters in this code much cleaner

Comment: I don't understand what the problem or the question is. Also why aren't you using properties? And why are all the members `public` (effectively making the getters and setters pointless)?

Comment: What is going wrong or what are you trying to accomplish? the question is not clear?

Comment: "declare the class in the main" - Do you mean assign values in `Main()`?

Comment: How does one use properties? Unholysheep, Please provide an example, in the meantime , I will research on that.

Answer (score 1):

Sins the question is not clear I've made up an example. I suggest from your question that you want to make an employee and display it. But this has to be done in the class and not in the Main method. Here is an example of creating and output an employee to console.

An property is just a short hand and will create at the background an public get method and a public set method and a private field to store the value. So in your code you can use a single property instead of adding manualy the private field and get/set method.

```
 // example property
 public string Name { get; set; }
```

Property is the same as the code below. but you can specify it in just one line.      private string Name;

```
 public string GetName(){
    return this.Name;
 }

 public string SetName(string name){
    this.Name = name;
 }
```

So in this code I use property s as you wanted. I've made the set private because the fields does not need to be chanced outside the class

```
class Program
{
    public static ItDepartment ItDepartment = new ItDepartment();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Press l for emoloyee list");
            Console.WriteLine("Press a for adding a employee");
            Console.WriteLine("Press x for closing program");

            // Get pressed key and take action
            switch (Console.ReadKey().KeyChar)
            {
                case 'a':
                    Console.Clear();
                    ItDepartment.Add();
                    break;
                case 'l':
                    Console.Clear();
                    ItDepartment.PrintItDepartmentEmployees();
                    break;
                case 'x':
                    return;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Not a vallid key");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Employee
{
    public string FirstName { get; private set; }
    public string LastName { get; private set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; private set; }
    public string Gender { get; private set; }
    public double StaffMenember { get; private set; }
    public DateTime DateOfEmployment { get; private set; }
    public string Position { get; private set; }
    public string Department { get; private set; }

    public void SetUser()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter First Name for employee");
        FirstName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Last Name for employee");
        LastName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter department for employee");
        Department = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter position for employee");
        Position = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter BirthDate for employee");
        BirthDate = GetDate();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter DateOfEmployment for employee");
        DateOfEmployment = GetDate();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter gender for employee");
        Gender = Console.ReadLine();
        StaffMenember = Program.ItDepartment.TotalEmployees();
    }

    private DateTime GetDate()
    {
        // 1. Ask the user to enter a date. 
        // 2. If it can't be converted to date like '132' it will try again and ask for the date ect..
        // 3. If success return date
        DateTime time;
        int counter = 0;
        do
        {
            if (counter != 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Could not convert input to date try again...");
            }
            time = StringToDate(Console.ReadLine());
            counter++;
        } while (time == DateTime.MinValue);
        return time;
    }
    private DateTime StringToDate(string input)
    {
        // 1. Get string input and try to convert it to a date.
        // 2. If it fails return the minimum version of datetime so we know it is wrong and can't be parsed
        return DateTime.TryParse(input, out DateTime date) ? date : DateTime.MinValue;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        // Return a string of all the fiels in the current employee
        return $"FirstName: {FirstName}\nLastName: {LastName}\nBirthDate: {BirthDate}\nGender: {Gender}\nStaffMenember: {StaffMenember}\nDateOfEmployment: {DateOfEmployment}\nPosition: {Position}\nDepartment: {Department}\n";
    }

}

class ItDepartment
{
    private List<Employee> _employees;

    public ItDepartment()
    {
        _employees = new List<Employee>();
    }

    public void Add()
    {
        // Create employee
        Employee emp = new Employee();
        // Call the method SetUser in Employee class
        emp.SetUser();
        // When the information is set add the employee object to the list
        _employees.Add(emp);
    }

    public void PrintItDepartmentEmployees()
    {
        // loop thrue all employees in the list and call method to string withs will return a string of the employee.
        foreach (var emp in _employees)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("================================================================================");
            // Write the string to the console.
            Console.WriteLine(emp.ToString());
        }
    }

    public int TotalEmployees()
    {
        // returns the total of employees in the list for the staff member.
        return _employees.Count;
    }
}
```

**Result after adding employee**
[image]

Comment: My apologies if my code looks like a mass, I am still a beginner, Timon your response was very helpful, The reason why I made the variable public is because, they are not accessible from outside the employee class and I have not mastered using getters and setters, I would like some help on that subject. I am trying to write a system that read input from a user and stores them in the variables created employee class (using getters and setter). Timon how will that code look if you make all those variables private, and if you change so it can request input from users?.

Comment: I've made an update hopefully this is what you are trying to accomplish. Read it carefully thru and if there's something you don't get google is your best friend:).

Comment: Timon You are the best man!! This is super helpful!! Thank you. There is still more I have to cover. But for now this is an big eye opener.